# Email through php and mail command not sending

Tags: linux, email, php, exim

I have two servers as to which one is hosting my company's email. The other one hosts a website where i have php scripts that sends mail to my mail server. When ever i send an email i get

```
550-Verification failed for <root@server.com>
550-The mail server could not deliver mail to root@server.com.  
The account or domain may not exist, they may be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries.
550 Sender verify failed
2013-05-31 10:12:41 1UiKS0-0006Vv-OQ Completed
```

The problem is i know that email account exists on our mail server and the weird thing is, if i send mail to my personal email account then it goes through without an issue. What could be the problem

Please note. root@server.com is an alias for the server im sending from

I ran exim -bt verifyfailedemail@domain.com and it returns

```
verifyfailedemail@domain.com
  router = lookuphost, transport = remote_smtp
  host mailServer.com [x.x.x.x] MX=0
```

Please help

To the people that will understand this is the php headers that i use in the mail. Its still not working even then

```
    $header .= "From: Uninstall <valid@validdomain.com>\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: valid@validdomain.com\r\n";
    $header .= "Return-Path: valid@validdomain.com\r\n";
    $header .= "Organization: Valid Company\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
```

Its still sending it as root@server.com

Comment: I fixed this issue by adding -f <emailaddress> parameter in my sendmail_path parameter in php.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination server is trying to verify that the sender's address (`root@server.com`) is a deliverable address before it accepts your message.  To do this, it connects to one of the `server.com` MX servers (or `server.com` itself if there are now MXs) and pretends to send an email to that address.  If `root@server.com` is undeliverable, your message will be discarded because it's been sent from an apparently invalid address.

If you know that `root@server.com` really is valid, it might be worth looking at the logs on the servers that handle `server.com` mail and see what happened when delivery was attempted.

Comment: this is what the recipient server says in the log files.
2013-05-31 10:12:40 H=ns1.dns.com (server.com) [x.x.x.x]:38714 F=<root@server.com> rejected RCPT <verifyfailemail@domain.com>: Sender verify failed

Comment: dns.com being my sending servers dns
server.com being the server im sending from
verifyfailemail@domain.com being the failed email address

Comment: So is `root@server.com` a real, deliverable address?

Comment: No its not but how do i change that? Because that was my first suspicion

Comment: You'll have to change your php scripts such that the email appears to come from a valid user.  Your mailserver is rejecting mail that doesn't come from an address that can receive mail.

Comment: Currently its root@<server host name> which is weird because exim is not supposed to send from that address. Im new with all of this and never encountered this before

Comment: So i can do this through the php mail headers?

Comment: I added all the headers and its not working still

Comment: Ho wdo i change my default email on the server